# Conditionally invoke method with same name from two different classes

Tags: java, lambda

I want an implementation where I need to invoke a method from one of two classes based on a condition. To illustrate, lets say I have two simplistic classes:

```
public class A implements IObject {
    @Override
    public void doIt() {
        System.out.println("OBJECTA");
    }
}
```

```
public class B implements IObject {
    @Override
    public void doIt() {
        System.out.println("OBJECTB");
    }
}
```

and an interface

```
public interface IObject {
    void doIt();
}
```

My method to dynamically call a class function is implemented as:

```
void call(String s, A a, B b, Consumer<IObject> o) {
    if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("CONDITION")) {
        o.accept(a);
    } else {
        o.accept(b);
    }
}
```

I can call the method as

```
A objectA = new A();
B objectB = new B();

call("CONDITION", objectA, objectB, IObject::doIt);
call("OTHER", objectA, objectB, IObject::doIt);
```

This will essentially invoke `doIt` on class `A` or `B` depending upon the condition parameter

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this by perhaps reducing the number of parameters an hence the function `call` signature?

Thanks

Comment: Will ```call``` only ever use ```IObject::doIt```?

Comment: @MichaelBianconi No there are around 20 such methods

Comment: Ternary operation to the help. `o.accept(s.equalsIgnoreCase("CONDITION") ? a : b)`

Answer (score 2):

For my understanding of your problem:

- You have a condition
- You have a context to use (object a and b)
- You would not ask such a question if there was not an intent to generalize your code for more than one condition or object (a, b). Otherwise, a ternary operator or a if would be far more easier to maintain (eg: `((condition) a:b).doIt()` vs the code below).

Why not using a pattern like this:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
String hint = ...;

List<Executor> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Executor("CONDITION"::equalsIgnoreCase, a::doIt));
list.add(new Executor(s -> true, b::doIt));
for (Executor executor : list) {
  if (executor.process(hint)) {
    break; 
  }
}
```

With `Executor` class:

```
class Executor {
  private final Predicate<String> predicate;
  private final Runnable runnable;
  ...
  public boolean process(String s) {
    if (!predicate.test(s)) {
      return false;
    }  
    runnable.run();
    return true;
  }
}
```

The loop will evaluate the condition, then run the code if true, otherwise continue onto the next element.

The Executor class is technically not bound to `a` or `b`; only the initial setup is.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete different approach, utilizing `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

/**
 *
 * @author ben
 */
public class Test {

    public interface IObject {
        void doIt();
    }
    public static class A implements IObject {
        @Override
        public void doIt() {
            System.out.println("OBJECTA");
        }
    }
    public static class B implements IObject {
        @Override
        public void doIt() {
            System.out.println("OBJECTB");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final boolean condition = true;

        IObject proxyObj =  (IObject)Proxy.newProxyInstance(Test.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[]{IObject.class}, new InvocationHandler() {
            @Override
            public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                if (condition)
                    new A().doIt();
                else
                    new B().doIt();
                return null;
             }
        });

        proxyObj.doIt();
    }
}
```

Here, you are creating a Proxy-Object for your Interface.
When you call `.doIt()` on this object, the invocation-handler will call the appropriate implementation, based on a condition.

You could then pass the proxy around and work with the invocation handler.

(It should be clear that this code should only give an idea and is only an example of how proxied interfaces/objects could be used to solve this problem.)

Comment: Don't you think that in such (simple) case and even more complex, a proxy is 1) overkill 2) not so good performance wise (comparing to calling either A/B doIt) 3) future headache when debugging :)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your use cases. If the use cases are as simple as what you've described, you could remove the Consumer and just call doIt directly in the call function. However, I would recommend generalizing the function even further:

```java
static <T> void ifElse(boolean decider, T optionA, T optionB, Consumer<T> callback) {
    if (decider) {
        callback.accept(optionA);
    } else {
        callback.accept(optionB);
    }
}
```

Then call it with:

```java
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
ifElse(condition.equals("CONDITION"), a, b, IObject::doIt);
```

Doing it this way is cleaner and more expandable. It also takes the same amount of code. (Untested, may have errors, but you get the idea). This approach is what you might see in purely ("purely") functional programming languages, where an if statement is just a function that takes a conditional and two functions (one for true, one for false).

Answer (score 1):

The above requirement can be implemented easily by using the ***'Factory design pattern'***

**The factory design pattern involves these 3 steps:**

1. Define the ***common interface*** for both the object types
2. Define the ***different classes that implement the common interface***
3. Create a ***Factory class with a static method*** that returns one of the object types based on the input condition

**Here is a working demo:**

```
// File name: Demo.java

interface IObject {
    public void doIT();
}

class A implements IObject {
    public void doIT() {
        System.out.println("DoIT - Class A");
    }
}

class B implements IObject {
    public void doIT() {
        System.out.println("DoIT - Class B");
    }
}

class IObjectFactory {
    static IObject getObject(String CONDITION) {
        if(CONDITION.equalsIgnoreCase("CONDITION")) {
            return (new A());
        }
        return (new B());
    }
}

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IObject io1 = IObjectFactory.getObject("condition");
        IObject io2 = IObjectFactory.getObject("no condition");
        io1.doIT();
        io2.doIT();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
> javac Demo.java

> java Demo

DoIT - Class A
DoIT - Class B
```

Comment: I do want to call `doIt` explicitly, but instead passed as a parameter since there are around 20 such methods